# Typescript solve lint function

Tags: typescript, vue.js, linter

I have this error returned by the linter with typescript :
Don't use `Function` as a type. The `Function` type accepts any function-like value.
It provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs.
It also accepts things like class declarations, which will throw at runtime as they will not be called with `new`.
If you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function shape.eslint@typescript-eslint/ban-types)

I use the notify plugin from quasar:
https://next.quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/notify

How can I resolve this error?

Here's my code

```
let masquerNotification:Function
    function afficherNotification () {
      if (notification.value && notification.value.message !== '') {
        masquerNotification = $q.notify({
          type: notification.value.type,
          message: notification.value.message,
          position: 'bottom-right',
          timeout: notification.value.timeout,
          actions: [{ icon: 'close', color: 'white' }]
        })
        void nettoyerNotification()
      }
      if (notification.value.masquer) {
        masquerNotification()
      }
    }
```

[image: error]!

Comment: Your example [doesn't even compile](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAtghgzgRwK4gE4DkD2YCWAzHAYxl0wDsAuAMSTMNLIFgAoCNiPW+nciGPAoQAWaLLkEkeZCAAoAlBADeLdu3yyy2fEUnkAdADcYwFBABkZiJvE6Gh4yj1QQcODADmICAEIAvL4gAckCFZVZVdlhEFAwtCQYIAIASBD1rfABPGTCIiLAMgAcQCis42yl7ExA9fKKAGhVcyJc3TxL0+IqjKqcWjxAG8KaIAsw4HAYSwIAjbDBMKABaVBx3ITBAweG2XGdMJDB2suI7bsddkH2wLe2YbnI4EoBtRQgicinCYDGQTYhCTDfVBTADuQgmvwgAF8ALqNXJQuTwiIGTA4AAmVnA8wyomOujI8mRbChxLeeA0+NODmqUWQaFCZLYdJiYm0JykRKG7FJ3KhQA), a linter error is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Please use ()=>void instead of Function Type.

```
let masquerNotification: () => void = () => {
  if (notification.value && notification.value.message !== '') {
    masquerNotification = $q.notify({
      type: notification.value.type,
      message: notification.value.message,
      position: 'bottom-right',
      timeout: notification.value.timeout,
      actions: [{ icon: 'close', color: 'white' }],
    });
    void nettoyerNotification();
  }
  if (notification.value.masquer) {
    masquerNotification();
  }
};
```

or

```
let masquerNotification: () => void = () => {
  function afficherNotification(){
    if (notification.value && notification.value.message !== '') {
      masquerNotification = $q.notify({
        type: notification.value.type,
        message: notification.value.message,
        position: 'bottom-right',
        timeout: notification.value.timeout,
        actions: [{ icon: 'close', color: 'white' }],
      });
      void nettoyerNotification();
    }
    if (notification.value.masquer) {
      masquerNotification();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: It's not working, I have this error :
Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(): void'.

Comment: @franfrLor This solution [works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtghgzgRwK4gE4DkD2YCWAzHAYxl0wDsAuACgEoBeAPgDdMcATAKA7yTMNLIQYeAoQAWaLLlEkc5CLQgBvDgF8usRCgzZ8RWfLpCRRCTun6BQA) for `masquerNotification = afficherNotification `. Where else are you assigning `masquerNotification`?

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: It's not working : https://ibb.co/9tsFMrC
I'm not calling elsewhere masquerNotification
It's Function with an uppercase F and not a lowercase

Comment: Always in error : https://ibb.co/GWFSGNp
Have you a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, where an array of classes was passed to the method `isAllowed(Classes)` and a check for every item was performed: `instance of Class`.

I found that it is possible to use an analog of `Function`: `NewableFunction`.

This is still not the right solution to the problem, but it helps with this case.

You can read this [doc](https://github.com/cyberspacedk/Typescript-book/blob/master/docs/types/callable.md) about callable and newable function types.